# weird MS Access problem : SELECT after UPDATE not consistent

Tags: winforms, ms-access, select

I have 2 data tables in an MS Access database. My winform will do UPDATE first, then SELECT.

The UPDATE always work, i.e. it correctly updates the database with correct values from textboxes.

The SELECT joins the 2 datatables. Most of the time the SELECT returns correct tuples from the join. But once in a while, the very last tuple would contain partial data as if the UPDATE is not executed on that one.

This is what I do. 
In method A,  connection.open, update query, connection.close.

In method B, connection.open, select query, connection.close.

I call method A, then method B. So things should happen sequentially.

If I put sleep(500) between the 2 methods, the race condition is gone. But I don't understand where it comes from....

Comment: Migrating to SQL Server is not an option? :-)

Comment: What are you using to run the queries?  Is the race condition eliminated if you stop closing the connection between queries?  Try connection.open, update query, select query, connection.close.

Comment: What happens if you re-use a single connection in both methods A and B (rather than independently opening and closing a connection in each method)?

Comment: To draw out @HansUp's suggestion, the point is that Jet/ACE works better with a persistent connection, because it's file-based, not a database server.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using ADO then it’s a well know “feature” of JET. Here is an example from Microsoft with a solution at the bottom to synchronise the database

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200300